# Continue after reboot Linux custom script - Azure ARM template

Tags: json, linux, azure

I am trying to build ARM JSON template and facing a problem with custom script extension and request for your help.

This is the sample script that I am executing as a part of virtual machine extensions (Linux).

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT="$1"
export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY="$2"
AZURE_STORAGE_CONTAINER="$3"
yum update -y
reboot
yum install -y epel-release
yum install -y gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel ksh m4 sshpass nodejs npm
```

With this script the VM was able to install updates and reboot. However the command "yum install -y epel-release" and following commands were not executed. And also while deployment this operation hangs and timeouts.

Can you help suggest how to solve this situation using JSON ARM template or custom script extension or using any Linux workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

probably powershell dsc can help you achieve that ([configure certain properties to force configuration to continue after reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535306/dsc-configuration-keeps-restarting)), or split your configuration into 2 scripts and deploy them independently of each other, so the first script reboots the machine, and after that second script should start working as soon as the VM becomes available and waagent talk to Azure.

Comment: thanks, i tried the split way. But somehow the script which did reboot never ends and other script is not downloaded to waagent. The operation status did not change to 'OK' and fails with timeout, can you suggest what might go wrong.